# Magento 2: How to put default value in yes/no field of widget.xml in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, widget

I am creating custom widget in Magento 2. I have created widget.xml file to create this. All things are fine and widget option is showing as well in admin.

Only I want selected value "Yes" instead of "No". Right now it is "No" as default selected value.

Here is the code I am using for select box in widget.xml

```
<parameter name="chart_layout" xsi:type="select" visible="true" source_model="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno" sort_order="2">
   <label translate="true">Full Width</label>
</parameter>
```

I am getting below section as screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If default values are not working for `YesNo` (I don't have time to dig) then you could always cheese the system for the time being and try to find a cleaner solution:

```
<parameter name="chart_layout" xsi:type="select" visible="true">
    <label translate="true">Full Width</label>
    <options>
        <option name="yes" value="1" selected="true">
            <label translate="true">Yes</label>
        </option>
        <option name="no" value="0">
            <label translate="true">No</label>
        </option>
    </options>
</parameter>
```

Comment: Not working, I get following error: Element 'parameter', attribute 'value': The attribute 'value' is not allowed

Comment: I've changed the answer to allow for a temporary fix.